# Problema con Exponential Smoothing

Tags: python, jupyter, machine-learning

como va? Luego de instalar la libreria, para hacer dicho algoritmo me tira este incoveniente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya he probado, desde instalarla con conda y con python, completas y nada aun.

Comment: Hola! Pues el lío es que no sabemos si estás instalando esas librerías en un entorno que no es el que usa tu notebook. O si usas la versión de sktime que no corresponde a lo que intentas usar y los módulos son diferentes. Hace falta muuuucha info sobre tu entorno para poder intentar ayudarte. Versión de python? Versión de la librería que intentas usar? Cómo la instalaste? Qué sale en consola al instalarla? Siéntete libre de [edit] tu pregunta y añadir toda esta info, ojala como texto y no con imágenes

Comment: Si, es el python 3.9 de version y la libreria de la instale como dice esta documentacion https://www.sktime.org/en/stable/installation.html

Comment: Pues ahí mismo en la [documentación de la API](https://www.sktime.org/en/latest/api_reference/utils.html) no se ve por ninguna parte `sktime.utils.plotting.forecasting`.